# Storing pure text from a textarea to a MySQL database correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql, textarea

I have a big textarea where text can be written.

```
 <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
```

I'm trying to store pure text (any human language) from this into a database (text field).

The problem: when I copy certain text from other websites some characters return as unicode, for example a `’` became `%u2019` (while a `´` from my own keyboard stays `´`). I supose this is because it's a different text style/format.

After this there is mysqli_real_escape_string but this seems to be working fine so far.

The question: how can I replace this unicode or avoid inputs like that? I might have forgotten to specify something about text formats (in the header?).

Comment: use utf-8 encoding in your header

Comment: Maybe this helps [PHP and MySQL: going fully UTF-8 for real](http://shebang.ws/full-unicode-utf8-php-mysql.html)

Comment: @Deepu, He is having trouble saving unicode text into the database, not displaying it on the page.

Comment: Actually when I echo the POST['textareaname'] (before storing in the database) it is already in unicode %u2019. I believe this shoulnd't be ? Header is set to UTF-8. It only happens with a certain format of characters. This character for example: ’ Some other characters just return a ? sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that the data being passed to the database connection is unicode (and hasn't been escaped, etc), then your problem may be in the database driver itself.

Make sure that it is set to `UTF-8`.

#### Checklist

1. Ensure that the data going in is unescaped (with exception of apostrophes, quotes, etc)
2. Ensure that the database driver is set to send data in `UTF-8` encoding (e.g. for PDO: `$dbHandle = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf-8", $dbUser, $dbPass);`. Note the `charset` section.
3. Ensure that the column collation is set to a `UTF-8`-compatible encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Use: **html_entity_decode**

```
<textarea class="textarea"><?php echo html_entity_decode($text_to_show); ?></textarea>
```

or maybe:

```
<textarea class="textarea"><?php echo html_entity_decode($text_to_show, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?></textarea>
```

make sure to have some utf8 database and not the default latin1.

Also if you are using html5 doctype then dont forget to type:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this on your server:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
```

Take a look what charset is your server configured to, to if needed change this to `UTF-8`

Take a look at: [Configuring MySQL To Use UTF-8](http://cameronyule.com/2008/07/configuring-mysql-to-use-utf-8/)